# Not able to retrieve/copy xml data from a string to a file

Tags: xml, perl

Problem Description:
 I have an xml file whose contents i copied to a variable to pass it through a HTTP message. Once i receive the HTTP message i tried to copy it back to a file and it doesn't seem to work.

I have done the below

```
if(-f $xml_file) {
            open (FH, "< $xml_file") || die "error", "Can't open schema file $xml_file:$!";
            while(<FH>) { $xml_content .= $_ . "\\n"; }
            close(FH);
        }
```

and i assigned the $xml_content to the html_header->{'xml_content'} which i defined.

i tried to copy the content back to a file using

```
  my $xml_data = html_header->{'xml_content'};  
  my $file_xml;
  write_file('$file_xml', $xml_data);
```

It doesn't work.
I want to copy the $file_xml to a specific location for later use.

AM a doing anything wrong here. or my understanding of the write_file functionality in File::Slurp qw(write_file) is wrong.

Could someone point out the mistake...i tried to do it other ways as well...but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Also, why are you appending `\\n` to each line (possibly after the newline)?

Comment: Its not writing the $xml_data to the $file_xml. As i am copying the content as a string...i thought adding a \n at the end would help differentiate between lines...when i read.

Comment: i get the error "Use of uninitialized value $file_xml " when i use the $file_xml at a later point.

Comment: What do mean by **"i assigned the $xml_content to the html_header->{'xml_content'} which i defined."**? You could create a hash ref html_header->{'xml_content'} with key as line number and value as $_ . You will not need to append values to $xml_content.

Comment: `write_file('$file_xml', $xml_data);` it should be like `write_file("$file_xml", $xml_data);`

Comment: `use strict; and use warnings;` are available in your code?

Comment: Thanks ssr1012. I found the problem when i added use strict; and use warnings. Yes, the write_file syntax you mentioned works.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
write_file('$file_xml', $xml_data);
```

Variables aren't expanded inside single-quotes. This creates a file with the name `$file_xml`. I think you probably meant:

```
write_file($file_xml, $xml_data); # No quotes needed.
```

Comment: Thanks Dave for your inputs. the syntax is write_file("$file_xml", $xml_data). I realized it when you pointed out about single quotes.

Comment: No. The syntax is (as I wrote in my answer) `write_file($file_xml, $xml_data)`. Sure your version works too, but why have the pointless quotes around `$xml_file`?